# Inline form Validation

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I'm trying to get my form to validate inline but can't seem to get the right syntax, at the moment I have this, which does nothing yet. The first function, formhandler is meant to change the span elements text if the element gets blured and take away the error text once the field is focused at the moment it does neither of these.

```
<html>
<script type = "text/javascript">
document.getElementById("form").onfocus = function formHandler()    {
    for(var i = 0; i < document.getElementById("form").length; i+=1){
        if(document.getElementById("form").elements[i].type == 'text') {
            if(document.getElementById("form").elements[i].focus()) {
                var onode = document.getElementById("form").elements[i].nextSibling;
                onode.innerHTML = "";
                valid = true;
            }
            else if(document.getElementById("form").elements[i].blur()) {
                var onode = document.getElementById("form").elements[i].nextSibling;
                onode.innerHTML = "Please Fill in Field";
                valid = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
function validate() {
    var valid = false;
    for(var i = 0; i < document.getElementById("form").length; i+=1){
        if(document.getElementById("form").elements[i].type == 'text') {
            if(document.getElementById("form").elements[i].value == "") {
                var onode = document.getElementById("form").elements[i].nextSibling;
                onode.innerHTML = "Please Fill in Field";
                valid = true;
            }
            else{
                var onode = document.getElementById("form").elements[i].nextSibling;
                onode.innerHTML = "";
                valid = false;
            }
        }
    }
}

document.getElementById("form").onsubmit = validate;
</script>
<head>
    <title>Question 1 / Vraag 1 - Basic JavaScript Validaton / Basiese JavaScript validasie
    </title>
    <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <form method="get" action="" id = "form">
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td> Firstname:</td>
    <td> <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" /><span id="fnError">
    </span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td> Surname:</td>
    <td> <input type="text" name="surname" id="surname" /><span id="snError">
    </span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td> Age:</td>
    <td> <input type="text" name="age" id="age" /><span id="aError">
    </span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>  Email:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="email" id="email" /><span id="eError">
    </span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td colspan="2"><input type="button" value="Validate" onclick = "validate()"/></td></tr>
    </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to achieve this without the use of jquery, so please don't suggest it, thanks in advance.

Comment: *can't seem to get the right syntax*: Can you elaborate? What's is it doing wrong? What isn't it doing right? Is there any place in the source code to which you can narrow down the problem?

Comment: @David sorry, The first function, formhandler is meant to change the span elements text if the element gets blured and take away the error text once the field is focused at the moment it does neither of these.

Comment: try debugging or put alerts in between and see where its breaking. Check of syntax errors too.

Comment: I'm working on my answer. Might take a while!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are problems I found in your code:

- Line 1: Forms don't have a `.focus` method. What did you mean for that to do?
- Line 2: Change `.length` to `.elements`:

  ```
  for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementById("form").elements.length; i++ ) {
      var node = document.getElementById("form").elements[i];
      ...
  ```

  <sub>The elements in the form are now aliased as `node`.</sub>
- Lines 4: The `.focus`/`.blur` method doesn't return true if the element is out of focus. We're going to have to do it ourselves:

  ```
  node.onfocus = function() { this.isInFocus = true; };
  node.onblur  = function() { this.isBlurred = !this.isInFocus; };
  ```

  The resulting code is as follows:

  ```
  if ( node.isInfocus ) { ... }

  else if ( node.isBlurred ) { ... }
  ```
- Line 9: Refer to above.
- Wrap the code in a `window.onload` to be able to use the DOM elements when the DOM has loaded.

This is your revised code; let me know if it works for you:

```
var nodes = document.getElementById('form').elements, node;

for ( var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++ ) (function(i) {

    nodes[i].onfocus = function() { this.isInFocus = true; };
    nodes[i].onblur  = function() { this.isBlurred = !this.isInFocus; };

})(i);


for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
    node = nodes[i];
    if (node.type == 'text') {
        if (node.isInFocus) {
            var onode = node.nextSibling;
            onode.innerHTML = "";
            valid = true;
        } else if (node.isBlurred) {
            var onode = node.nextSibling;
            onode.innerHTML = "Please Fill in Field";
            valid = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I removed the valid var since it wasn't declared, but it stil doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Crossman The code won't work because you have an `.onfocus` event handler on a `<form>` element. Why? Forms don't have an `.onfocus` handler. What did you intend for that to do?

Comment: I removed that though, I wasn't sure how to generalize the code to all form elements at first

Comment: @Crossman You're going to have to set a submit button to check if all the form elements have been filled out correctly by the user. When the submit button is clicked it should run the code in the for loop I gave you. But when you click the sumbit the form through the button, the focus will go off all elements, so there's no need to check if one is in focus or not. Just check if all elements are filled out correctly one by one.

Comment: Great answer, @David. +2 if I could ;)

Answer (score 0):

First major problem: you are trying to do all of this in the initial script load.  The main DOM is not yet loaded at that time so document.getElementById("form") won't find anything.  Do the function definitions in an onload handler.

Also, not sure what you are expecting "valid" to bind to in the first function.   Finally, once you have determined validity or not, you need to do something with the result.

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing dom elements which don't exist yet. One solution would be to move all your `<script>` tag before `</body>`, so elements exist when the script is executed. 
Another way, with pure javascript would be to do this:

```
<script>
window.onload = function(){
   //All your code here
}
</script>
```

(The `validate` function could be outside if you want)

Cheers

Comment: I attempted something similar, but it still wasn't giving me the desired effect.

Comment: I tested it and it works. So you should explain what's the desired effect.

Comment: I put the formHandlers code inside the window.onload function as you said. But on mine its not achieving the inline error checking with blur and focus as I wanted